# Checkbox in Zend Form

Tags: html, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am wonder that how can I built the following pattern in zend_form

```
<input type= "checkbox" name="some"/>click this checkbox
```

As when I add description, it set beneath the checkbox, and I want that it should be in front of the checkbox.

How can I get this. As I tried all possible techniques that I know like adding label, adding description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to do this.
Set `display:block; float:left;` properties to both input and label elements